# Offset in Excel 2007 only goes to certain point

Tags: excel, charts, excel-2007, offset

In Excel 2007 my formula for offset is not collecting all of my data. The data will be going into an excel chart I want the formula to collect from G28 to G200, but it stops at G111. Here is the full formula:

=OFFSET(TIJ!$G$28,0,0,COUNT(TIJ!$G$28:$G$200),1)

Any help is much appreciated.

Best,
Drew

Comment: Count will count only the cells with numbers in them.  What is the criteria for ending the range before row 200.

Comment: What do you get when you just calculate `COUNT(TIJ!$G$28:$G$200)`?

Comment: Why not just change `COUNT(TIJ!$G$28:$G$200)` to `173` ??? Will G28 and G200 move?

Comment: @JReid If we are goinf to hard code a range just put `=TIJ!$G$28:$G$200`

Comment: @ScottCraner Finally I got your attention! lol, jk. I do like the work you've been doing on this site though. In anycase, you are right, but I thought `=OFFSET(TIJ!$G$28,0,0,173,1)` would be hard-coding a number of cells rather than the range itself?

Comment: @JReid OFFSET is a Volatile Function so its use should be limited and in most cases can be replaced with INDEX to avoid volatility.

Comment: @ScottCraner now you've tickled my curiosity, can INDEX replace this function? If so, how?

Comment: `=INDEX(TIJ!G:G,28):INDEX(TIJ!G:G,COUNT(TIJ!$G$28:$G$200)+28)` @JReid

Comment: @ScottCraner Thanks!

Comment: I appreciate your responses Scott, nbaylay, and J. I am currently at work and will test out your concepts when I have a break from my actual work. Thanks.

Comment: Nbayly it goes all the way to 200.

Comment: The code does not work when I insert the formula into Name Manager, but works when inserted into a cell.

Comment: Using Index the formula only goes until 84.

Comment: I am also pulling the information that I want entered from a foreign worksheet.

Comment: Remember COUNT only counts the cells that have numbers.  So if some of the values are text that look like numbers or empty cells they will not count.  If you always want to use all the cells then just put `=TIJ!$G$28:$G$200`.  If you want it to go to the last cell with a number then use `=INDEX(TIJ!G:G,28):INDEX(TIJ!G:G,MATCH(1E+99,TIJ!G:G))` which will include every cell from G28 to the last cell in Column G with a number in it.

Comment: Sorry missed you are putting it in for a named range the columns must be absolute `=INDEX(TIJ!$G:$G,28):INDEX(TIJ!$G:$G,MATCH(1E+99,TIJ!$G:$G))`

Comment: It worked! Thanks Scott. If you could put it in the answer section then I will give it a positive mark.

Comment: Also, additional question. What would it be if I had two separate columns of information, one being the day of the week and other the month. I will still give Scott the positive mark no matter what.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To find a list of data points that are on going from a certain point (in this can G28). The equation also only surrounds relevant information in the excel spread sheet to a chart.

=INDEX(Sheetname!$X:$X,Y):INDEX(TIJ!$X:$X,MATCH(1E+99,TIJ!$X:$X))

X= is the column used

Y= is the row starting point